# Expressing many-to-many that is many-to-one with respect to a given attribute

Tags: database-design, rdbms, erd

I have come across (actually, came up with) the following design challenge. Suppose that, in a hospital, there is a many-to-many relationship between doctors and patients. Each doctor has a specialization (i.e. area of expertise) code. The challenge is to make sure that a patient will not have more than one doctor of any given specialization. I would prefer a solution that can be expressed in ERD, preferably without relationships that involve more than two entities.

I have thought of one solution, but I dislike it for it being artificial and for not being able to express it in ERD. The solution is to include doctor's specialization into the key in the Doctors table. Then, make the key of the table expressing the relationship between patients and doctors consist only of patient's ID and doctor's specialization (but not doctor's ID, which is used only as part of the foreign key to the Doctors table). Again, I am looking for a more natural solution that can be expressed in ERD.

Comment: I think the problem is the relationship between 'Patient' and 'Doctor' (and specialization as an attribute), due to the way it allows the relationship of many to many, so if you want to restrict for each specialization, then you will have to break this relationship and put a one-to-many relationship or something like that. On the other hand, it is unsustainable (Tables: `Doctor, Patient , Specialization`)

Comment: @R.García In the original problem, each specialization has a name, so I already had a separate table for specializations. I do not see in what way that helps though, which is probably the problem of unsustainability you referred to.

Comment: That it's, if you put a `Specialization` as a table, then you will need to associate with `Doctor` table and this relationship will be one-one. Because the other way it could be weird!

Comment: @R.García There can be many doctors in the hospital for a given specialization. In any case, if you think that you have a solution, would you like to expound on it in a reply?

Comment: Ok, then I will do 2 or 3  ERD design that you could use.

Comment: Please give DDL for a specific design to which this constraint applies. Give the DDL for your "one design". "Artificial" & "natural" don't mean anything, so please write more about your (granted, fuzzy) impressions & concerns, referencing the DDL. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: PS You're not clear yet, but this seems probably a faq. Google database/sql subtyping/polymorphism/hierrachies. You are typing doctors by specialty. The SQL design pattern to declaratively constrain an entity reference to be of some given type(s) is to use a FK with entity & desired type variant/tag, here doctor & specialty.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Relationship Diagrams are not very useful for specifying data integrity rules. Many common business rules cannot be adequately described in ERD notation and so the expressiveness of ERD is not a good guide to how to implement business rules.

If you are interested in a notation for expressing business rules then take a look at [Object Role Modelling](http://orm.net) which is far more precise and expressive than ERD.

SQL is not very good at implementing inter-relation constraints either. As an example of how easy this can be in RDBMS, here's a possible implementation of a relational database using the Tutorial D language. The constraint you want is implemented by a key {patno, spec} on a virtual relation (view) called patient_doc_spec.

```
VAR doctor REAL RELATION {doc CHARACTER, spec CHARACTER} KEY {doc};
VAR patient REAL RELATION {patno CHARACTER} KEY {patno};
VAR patient_doc REAL RELATION {patno CHARACTER, doc CHARACTER} KEY {patno,doc};
VAR patient_doc_spec VIRTUAL (patient_doc{patno,doc} JOIN doctor {doc,spec}) KEY {patno, spec};
```

Comment: Is it common to create a view just to easily enforce a functional dependency constraint?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Not very common in my experience. You could create patient_doc_spec as a table instead of a view, add suitable referential constraints and then you don't need the patient_doc table. I believe that is the solution you described in the second paragraph of your question.